# How to get pseudonyms from Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Want to extract Bob Dylan pseudonyms. His Wikidata page is https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q392

One way is to walk the following tree and parse value for `P742` (pseudonym): https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q392&format=json

But that's a lot of work and specific to Bob Dylan; other people with pseudonyms may have a different JSON structure.

This query works for his awards:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?linkTo ?linkToLabel {
  ?item wdt:P166 wd:Q37922 ;
        wdt:P910 wd:Q8064684 .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P166 ?linkTo ;
            wdt:P31 wd:Q5 } .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

as seen [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FlinkTo%20%3FlinkToLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP166%20wd%3AQ37922%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP910%20wd%3AQ8064684%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP166%20%3FlinkTo%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

The weakness is it uses the combination of "topic's main category" (`P910`) and the target "category" (`Q8064684`) to specify "Bob Dylan".

For that query, I can't find the method to use his QID (`Q392`).

I do not want to text search, as is proposed in [Group concat not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855767/group-concat-not-working), because there is more than one Bob Dylan. And many people with pseudonyms will not have a category, so that technique cannot be generalized.

This query works for occupations and uses his QID (`Q392`), not the Bob Dylan category (`Q8064684`) from the "awards" query.

```
SELECT * {
  SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    wd:Q392 wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;
            wdt:P106 ?occupation
    SERVICE wikibase:label {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
      ?occupation rdfs:label ?label
    }
  }
}
```

as seen [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2A%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ392%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP106%20%3Foccupation%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Foccupation%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

but I cannot find the right SPARQL query to select pseudonyms (which are text) as seen here: 
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q392

**How to write a Wikidata SPARQL query that uses a person's identifier (e.g. Q392 for Bob Dylan) and can be configured (easily toggled) to select either "award received" (P166), "occupations" (P106) or "pseudonym" (P742)?**

Comment: Another user confused by [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements) statements...

Comment: see the ranking of the statements, "best" is preferred: `SELECT * {
  SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    wd:Q392 wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;
            p:P742 ?statement.
            ?statement ps:P742 ?value .
  ?statement wikibase:rank ?rank .
  OPTIONAL { ?statement a ?best . }
           
  }
}`

Comment: So you can always use the query above to get all the data, not just the preferred one. Credits for the query go to StanislavKralin by the way ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100068/some-cities-arent-instances-of-city-or-big-city-odd-behaviour-of-wikidata))

Comment: yes, i did not know how to handle statements or truthy statements. let me study your comment to make sure i understand and can put it to work - be back to you.

Comment: it's not that difficult. just use the properties `p:PXXX' and `ps:PXXX' instead of 'wdt:PXXX`

Comment: @AKSW please post your answer and i will accept it